How to resolve OAuth2AuthenticationToken then integrating previous authentication into it
I have a security bean using keycloak as the authentication provider like this:
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain defaultSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity,
                                           ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository registrationRepository,
                                           ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository,
                                           AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler,
                                           AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler) {
        httpSecurity
            .csrf(ServerHttpSecurity.CsrfSpec::disable)
            .httpBasic(ServerHttpSecurity.HttpBasicSpec::disable)
            .formLogin(ServerHttpSecurity.FormLoginSpec::disable)
            .oauth2Login(spec -> spec
                .authenticationSuccessHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
                .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                .clientRegistrationRepository(registrationRepository))
            .exceptionHandling(spec -> spec
                .authenticationEntryPoint(accessDeniedHandler)
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler))
            .logout(spec -> spec
                .requiresLogout(ServerWebExchangeMatchers.matchers(
                    ServerWebExchangeMatchers.pathMatchers("/logout")))
                .logoutHandler(new DelegatingServerLogoutHandler(List.of(
                    new SecurityContextServerLogoutHandler(),
                    new WebSessionServerLogoutHandler())))
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new OidcClientInitiatedServerLogoutSuccessHandler(registrationRepository)));

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

This works fine so far as after authenticating with keycloak, i got back to the application with an OAuth2AuthenticationToken resolved by spring security. This OAuth2AuthenticationToken i can then use in my  custom ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler something like this:
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> onAuthenticationSuccess(WebFilterExchange webFilterExchange, Authentication authentication) {
        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            //do stuffs when user is authenticated with keycloak
        }
        return Mono.empty();
    }
}


As now i will have another different type of authentication providers used in my application which are resolved manually be the application and not by spring security, therefore i would like extend the OAuth2AuthenticationToken from spring with the information of the previous authentication provider which user was authenticated before being authenticated with keycloak. Therefore i would like to create a custom authentication class which extends the OAuth2AuthenticationToken and then pack inside of this new authentication class the previous authentication, something like:

@Getter
public class CustomKeycloakAuthentication extends OAuth2AuthenticationToken {

    private Authentication previousAuthentication;

    public CustomKeycloakAuthentication(Authentication previousAuthentication, OAuth2User principal, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, String authorizedClientRegistrationId) {
        super(principal, authorities, authorizedClientRegistrationId);
        this.previousAuthentication = previousAuthentication;
    }

    @Override
    public OAuth2User getPrincipal() {
        return super.getPrincipal();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return super.getCredentials();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId() {
        return super.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId();
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return super.getAuthorities();
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return super.isAuthenticated();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean authenticated) {
        super.setAuthenticated(authenticated);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return super.getDetails();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDetails(Object details) {
        super.setDetails(details);
    }

    @Override
    public void eraseCredentials() {
        super.eraseCredentials();
    }
    
}

My problem is that i am still getting stuck with how to resolve the OAuth2AuthenticationToken manually so that i can pack the previous authentication into my own CustomKeycloakAuthentication.
My idea is to have a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken which will firstly get the current authentication (before spring jumps in and does some magic stuffs with keycloak) then when somehow tell spring to pack this authentication to the CustomKeycloakAuthentication when resolving the OAuth2AuthenticationToken, but i don't know how to extend the security bean above to reach this. Can anyone please give me some hints? Thank you very much!
i read some documentations and tried local but no success
